# adding source code to build path?

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded an API but there is no jar file in it. It has the packages(folders) and the source code. I tried adding this in various ways in Eclipse but still I don't get the "import ...." when I press F2 on the underlined red classname. I have added projects and Jars in Eclipse all the time and it has worked. Since this is the source code should I take any extra steps in order to make it work?

Regards!

Comment: did you tried right click on a directory and then add-to-buildpath?

Comment: what I did is that I right clicked on the project in Eclipse when to properties -> Java Build Path -> Liberies tab -> Add external class folder. I also tried it in the Source tab. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create jar from the classes you have received in API packaging and place that jar into the classpath of the project

Enjoy !!!

Comment: This is the better approach, and what you should try to do. However, if you really want to do exactly what you asked for whatever reason, @home answer is the way to go

Comment: I see, what is the best way around creating a jar file from source?

Comment: The API which you have download will have a build script. You can find build that `build.xml` using `ant` and in the build scrit you can find the label or command for creating the jar.

Answer (score 3):

If the source is available to you (.java files) you must create a new **source folder**, then copy the source tree (root package e.g. the folder `com` or `org`) into the new **source folder** just by using a standard file explorer and copy&paste:

[image]

**Edit:** You could add the source files to your existing source folder as well, but I'd avoid that. Best solution would be to create a separate Java project containing just the source files of the external library. You also need proper code management, so that you do not accidentially make changes to the external source files!